# How do you draw a rectangle based on mousemotion in pygame

Tags: python, events, graphics, pygame

I am attempting to create a paint program in pygame. It requires the user to be able to draw a rectangle on the screen by clicking and dragging.

```
pygame.draw.rect(screeny, (255,255,255), [posi[0], posi[1], e.pos[0]-posi[0], e.pos[1]-posi[1]], 1)
square = pygame.draw.rect(screeny, color, [posi[0], posi[1], e.pos[0]-posi[0], e.pos[1]-posi[1]], 1)

pygame.display.flip()
```

However, the rectangle is not displayed properly. How would I only draw one rectangle starting from the mouse button down point going to the mouse button up point?

Comment: Polygons. http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html look at the polygon section.

Comment: But I don't want an anti-re-sizable shape. I **want** a shape (rect) that can get re-sized based to events. I know how to draw stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough code to work with from your example. But I was able to make a little bit of code that creates boxes and leaves it on the screen.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import * //Allows MOUSEMOTION in stead of pygame.MOUSEMOTION

window_size = (800, 600)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
mousepos = None
boxes = []

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

while 1:

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mousepos = [event.pos[0], event.pos[1], 0, 0]

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            boxes.append(mousepos)
            mousepos = None

        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION and mousepos != None:
            mousepos = [mousepos[0], mousepos[1], event.pos[0] - mousepos[0], event.pos[1] - mousepos[1]]

    for box in boxes:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, box, 1)

    if mousepos != None:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, mousepos, 1)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

I hope this helps.

NOTE: Be careful with the event queue, it's dangerous. NEVER use it for checking key presses. Use "pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_(Key here)]". If you need to prevent this from triggering twice, create a list that holds the previous values like so:

```
prev = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if prev[K_(key here)] != pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_(Key here)]
    do your stuff...
```